# Open Specific Tab on External Website (No Access to External Site Code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, href

I've seen a few similar answers but they all rely on adding JS / JQuery to the external website, I don't have access to the code on the external website so that won't work for me.

I want to add a link on my website, when the link is selected a new window should open and the specific tab should be active / selected.

How can I achieve this when I don't have access to the external website's code, only my own site.

- The external website is https://mcnmedia.tv/iframe/2684
- The tab I want to open is 'Recordings'

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<a href="https://mcnmedia.tv/iframe/2684#recordingtab" target="_blank">View Recordings</a>
```

Comment: Given that the URL doesn't change when 'Recordings' is clicked you cannot target that tab directly when redirecting a user. What you're trying to do is not possible without that site amending the way their navigation works.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah ok, I thought there may have been some way I could achieve this. I guess not :/ Thanks for looking